# What is node-persist

Tags: node.js, npm

While watching online lectures of Node.js on Udemy, I came across the term 
**node-persist**.

I googled the term but didn't find any satisfactory explanation.

Kindly someone explain what node-persist is by definition?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**node-persist** is an npm package that you can easily use in your project by executing the command:

```
$ npm install node-persist
```

node-persist is a super-easy asynchronous persistent *data structures* in **Node.js**, modeled after **HTML5 localStorage**

Node-persist doesn't use a **database**. Instead, **JSON** documents are stored in the file system for persistence. Because there is no network overhead, node-persist is just about as fast as a database can get.

Node-persist uses the HTML5 localStorage API, so it's easy to learn.

How to use :

```
const storage = require('node-persist');

//you must first call storage.init
await storage.init( /* options ... */ );
await storage.setItem('name','yourname')
console.log(await storage.getItem('name')); // yourname
```

If you wish to learn more about node-persist visit [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-persist) site.

Comment: So we can  say it database although it is not database but it works like data base...??

Comment: Yes, it stores your data but in JSON format no particular columns are required as a traditional database.If this answer solves your query please accept it as a solution.

Comment: Yes thanks alot. It help for me. But I have got an other problem if you can help please? Nd If you think my ques is well please upvote my question :)

Comment: Yes sure. But I recommend if your problem is not related to node.js or npm post a different question.

Comment: I'm a little confused about "filesystem". Filesystem on user's computer (locally) or on the remote server ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in module/library in Node.js that is called [node-persist](https://github.com/simonlast/node-persist), however there is a 3rd party NPM module called `node-persist`. That module aims to provide very simple persistent storage using the file system and refers to itself as "LocalStorage for the Server".